# Create multiple screens with a list of installed applications with GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-launcher

There is a primitive launcher with the ability to set its own background, in which with GridView all user applications are displayed. At the moment, I can view all applications scrolling through the list, but it's necessary to realize this by the ability to switch between screens if all applications do not fit on one screen. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to have many lists of apps on different pages (using view pager)?

Comment: The hardware task is to implement the n-th number of screens that contain a list of installed applications, according to the type of application menu in Google start laucher.